# Fluid three column layout with fixed width center column

Tags: html, css

I want to obtain this layout:

```
<------------ Browser Width 100% ------------>
[left][----- center: fixed width -----][right]
```

- The center column has a fixed pixel width
- The left and right columns fill in the remaining viewport width equally

The example below breaks when the viewport width is not wide enough, and getting the correct percentage width is hard because of the fixed width center column.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F90;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
}
.center {
  width: 500px;
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left (fill available space)</div>
<div class="center">fixed width</div>
<div class="right">right (fill available space)</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Three ways to achieve a fluid / fixed column layout

### Method #1 - [with `display: table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values)

This is one of the easiest methods and has good browser support.

**Compatibility:** [IE8 + and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

- body gets `display: table` - this could also be applied to a div wrapper instead.
- `table-layout: fixed` ensures the middle column remains fixed width
- the direct div children of body get `display: table-cell`
- the body gets a `min-width` to ensure the left and right columns do not get too small
- the middle column is fixed at your desired width (500px in this example)
- the left and right columns inherit the remaining page width

#### #1 - Working Example

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 800px;
}
body > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.left {
  background: #000;
}
.middle {
  background: #F00;
  width: 500px;
}
.right {
  background: #F90
}
```

```html
<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="middle">

</div>

<div class="right">

</div>
```

---

### Method #2   - with `display: inline-block` and [`width: calc(x - y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

**Compatibility:** Calc is compatible in [IE 9 + and most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). There are javascript fallbacks available as well.

- The direct div children of body are given `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`. They will align themselves to the top of the browser window on the same line
- The middle column gets its fixed width
- The left and right columns are given `calc(50% - 250px)`; this calculates 50% of the page width minus half of the width of the fixed middle column.
- [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) incorporates padding and borders into the width and height

#### #2 - Working Example

Note how the closing and opening divs tags have no gaps between them; [this is to prevent an inline gap between elements.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  min-width: 800px;
}
body > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 250px);
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  background: #000;
}
.middle {
  background: #F00;
  width: 500px;
}
.right {
  background: #F90
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="right"></div>
```

---

### Method #3 - [with `display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

This is a really awesome method, but is not supported with older browsers :(

**Compatibility:** [IE11 and most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

- The body gets `display: flex` and [`height: 100vh` (100% of the viewport height)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)
- The direct children get `flex: 1` and will grow and shrink
- The middle column gets its fixed width and `flex: 0 0 auto`; it will **not** grow or shrink

Here is [a useful guide to Flexbox.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

#### #3 - Working Example

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 800px;
}
body > div {
  flex: 1;
}
.left {
  background: #000;
}
.middle {
  background: #F00;
  width: 500px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.right {
  background: #F90
}
```

```html
<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="middle">

</div>

<div class="right">

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why my question was downvoted.
anyway, your answer is very good.
very helpful for me. thank you :)

Comment: `Display: grid` is the fourth way, but not all browsers support this new invention yet

Comment: The flexbox example doesn't work when the viewport is not big enough (same problem as OP describes in their question). In fact all three examples have that problem.

Comment: @TylerH well it's to be expected when you have a fixed width somewhere! The 800px min width I went with is arbitrary. A bit of `@media` magic to reduce the fixed center column on smaller viewports to a smaller fixed width (or change the layout completely for smaller screens) is straightforward enough. The examples I made are only examples and can easily be adapted to reduce the middle fixed width or change the layout completely with smaller viewports.